# How can I reference a method with async to another method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, console

I'm trying to reference this method within another method. How can I call this method within another? public async Task submit_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e); I'm trying to reference it like submit_ClickAsync(object sender, eventArgs e) within another method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can await it from an `async` method: `await submit_ClickAsync(this, EventArgs.Empty);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear.
If you want to call an async method in another Method , it would be like this.

```
public async Task Submit_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Submit_ClickAsync2(sender,e);
}
```

if you want to return an async method in another method, it would be like this:

```
public Task Submit_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    return Submit_ClickAsync2(sender,e);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to call the method with the paramters. An example might be as follows:

```
private void CallAsycMethod(){
submit_ClickAsync(this, null);
}
```

A better way would be to use the parameters as they are meant to be used.

```
private void BtnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
submit_ClickAsync(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: This is not what the question is about. They have to use `await` to _wait_ for the method.

Comment: Only the presence of an async function is mentioned by the OP, not the awaiting of it.